# How can I find a document by it's objectid with MongoDB atlas app service functions

Tags: realm, mongodb-atlas

Seems simple enough. I have a collection with existing records.

When I query for it with MongoDB compass:

```
use SomeDatabase
db.MyCollection.findOne({})
```

It finds the result.

When I try and create a simple app services function to retrieve it:

```js
// Testing console
exports();
```

```js
// Function script
exports = async function(assetId, rendition) {
  var serviceName = "mongodb-atlas";
  var dbName = "SomeDatabase";
  var collName = "MyCollection";
  var collection = context.services.get(serviceName).db(dbName).collection(collName);


  var findResult;
  try {
    findResult = await collection.findOne({});

  } catch(err) {
    console.log("Error occurred while executing findOne:", err.message);

    return { error: err.message };
  }

  // To call other named functions:
  // var result = context.functions.execute("function_name", arg1, arg2);

  return {
    result: findResult,
  };
};
```

I get the following error regardless of how I try to query the database:

```
Error occurred while executing findOne: $in needs an array
```

I think I might be going insane.

Comment: What are you expecting here `findResult = await collection.findOne({});` and, do you (as the authenticated user) have permission to access that collection? The question leaves out some details so can you clarify? What SDK are you using - it's tagged as Realm but that's  more app services.

Comment: @Jay sorry yes its more an app services question but couldn't find the relevant tag.

Comment: Discovered the problem was with a rule that was looking for an item in a user data. The test user was missing user data so failed at this point. What confused me, was I assumed that no rules were being applied within the function, so had no clue why I was seeing an $in error, with an essentially empty query. I literally clicked it could be due to the rules after submitting the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like app services are wrapping any calls you make with their own to ensure your user who calls the function is allowed to access objects.

This is actually an error from their code, when trying to execute rules. Well that was frustrating.

Comment: I don't think this is a good assumption and 'wrapping calls you make with their own' isn't really how it works, and I don't really think this is an 'answer' but more of a comment to your own question. There are a number of things that would cause that code to fail.